# Laravel not creating custom log file

Tags: php, laravel, logging

For local development, I want to write debug messages to a separate log file called localDebug.log. Therefore, I have set up logging.php as follows:

```php
'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'localDebug'),
'channels' => [
        // 'stack' => [
        //     'driver' => 'stack',
        //     'channels' => ['papertrail'],
        // ],
        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
        'localDebug' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/localDebug.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
        // ... more
```

Then, I log like that:

```php
Log::debug('Some value: '.$rv);
```

But the logfile is not being created in /storage/logs. I'm on Linux Mint, if that matters, and permissions for user www-data have been set (showing details for /logs here):

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data www-data     4096 Jan 18 12:45 ./
```

What am I missing here? Is the config wrong or is it still a permissions issue?

Comment: Have you defined the ```LOG_CHANNEL``` in .env file?

Comment: Alternatively you can also do `Log::channel('localDebug')->debug(...);` But is indeed better to define it in the .env files, this way you can just use `Log::debug`, without having to define the channel all the time.

Comment: @geertjanknapen Thanks, that did the trick ;-) Works exactly as expected now, with my custom log messages going to the separate file and the regular (system) ones going to laravel.log

Comment: @GhanuBha no not yet, but since I want to separate my custom log messages from system messages I'll probably have leave it that way.

Comment: Please check in your ```.env``` there will be a variable. Because Laravel is default add that variable in ```.env``` and if you do not find that there then run ```php artisan o:c```